# Creating a image of a panel

Tags: python, wxpython

I would like to create and save a wxpython panel as image.  I do not know if this is even possible and have not been able to find any information. If anybody has any info on how i would go about this it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's inside the Panel? Is it manually painted, or using child controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I find some information after posting a question.  The following code does exactly what I am looking for.

```
def OnSaveToFile(self, event):
    context = wx.ClientDC(self)
    memory = wx.MemoryDC()
    x, y = self.ClientSize
    bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(x, y, -1)
    memory.SelectObject(bitmap)
    memory.Blit(0, 0, x, y, context, 0, 0)
    memory.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
    bitmap.SaveFile('test.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
```

I got it from this link http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages